# Why is java -version giving me this?

Tags: java, uninstall

i uninstalled java using the commands:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove "java" "/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java"
sudo update-alternatives --remove "javac" "/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/javac"
sudo update-alternatives --remove "javaws" "/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/javaws"
```

the i did:

```
sudo rm -r /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131
```

i also typed the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove oracle-java8-installer
```

when i type `java -version` now i am getting:

```
nehal@nehal-Inspiron-5559:~$ java -version
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.9-jre-headless
 * openjdk-9-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

Previously i used to get **no such file/directory**,have i correctly uninstalled it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you correctly uninstalled Java. The information where you *could* get Java, if you wanted it, is a service of the alternatives system.

Comment: should i manually remove the classpath set in /etc/environment  and ./bashrc?

Comment: @nrb You're talking about the environment variable CLASSPATH, correct? You can remove the lines setting the env var, but you don't have to.